# jQuery issue on prevent Click event on sub list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/f27bp/) and let me know how I can stop sliding on clicks on sub list of `Two` and `Three`.
As you can see the jQuery is functioning fine on clicks on `parent` list but when user clicks on childes still sliding the list which must not. Can you please let me know how I can stop this?

```
 $(".parent").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".musthidden").slideUp();
     $(this).each(function () {
         if ($('.musthidden', this).css('display') == 'none') {
             $(".musthidden", this).slideDown();
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/CcQE5/)

```
 $(".parent > a").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".musthidden").slideUp();
     $(this).parent(".parent").each(function () {
         if ($('.musthidden', this).css('display') == 'none') {
             $(".musthidden", this).slideDown();
         }
     });
 });
```